# How do I change the automatic time stamp table entry from Epoch time to now?

Tags: java, android, date, android-sqlite

How do I change the automatic time stamp table entry from Epoch time to now?

Currently my table is set using the following:

```
CREATE  TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS Calculations (calculation_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , data_id INTEGER, area_id INTEGER, date DATETIME NOT NULL;
```

I add entries to the table using the following:

```
INSERT INTO Calculations (data_id , area_id , date ) VALUES (?1, ?2, date('now') );
```

When I recall the date values they are all: `Wed Dec 31 17:00:02 MST 1969`

It was my understanding that `date('now')` would produce the current date.

How do I insert the **current date** into a android-sqlite table entry?

**Additional Clarification:**

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) supports five date and time functions as follows:

```
date(timestring, modifier, modifier, ...)
time(timestring, modifier, modifier, ...)
datetime(timestring, modifier, modifier, ...)
julianday(timestring, modifier, modifier, ...)
strftime(format, timestring, modifier, modifier, ...)
```

Time Strings

A time string can be in any of the following formats:

```
YYYY-MM-DD
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
HH:MM
HH:MM:SS
HH:MM:SS.SSS
now
DDDDDDDDDD
```

I am trying to use the `date(now)` to insert the current date.
This enters Epoch time instead of the current date.

Comment: There is no datetime type in sqlite, you will need to store it as a string, the easiest way to get the current typed date is to use the joda time package, failing that you can extract it from calendar.

Comment: @dave good point. I understand there is no datetime type and its actual type is just a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After feedback I changed how I was retrieving the stored date from the Database.

Previously:

```
int date = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"));
calculation.setDate(new Date(date));
```

Currently:

```
String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"));
String[] dateArray = date.split("-"); //Split Year-Month-Day
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(Integer.parseInt(dateArray[0]), Integer.parseInt(dateArray[1]), Integer.parseInt(dateArray[2]) );
```

From there I ended up changing how the `Calculation` date was set to use a `Calendar` instead of a `Date` Object

Answer (score 2):

I think your sqlite logic is correct. You might be wrong in somewhere else. I used sqlite3 and tested the following using your scripts. Both date() and date('now') seem working.

```
sqlite> select date();
2015-06-24

sqlite> CREATE  TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS Calculations (calculation_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , data_id INTEGER, area_id INTEGER, date DATETIME NOT NULL);
sqlite> select * from Calculations;
sqlite> INSERT INTO Calculations (data_id , area_id , date ) VALUES (1, 2, date('now') );
sqlite> select * from Calculations;
1|1|2|2015-06-24

sqlite> INSERT INTO Calculations (data_id , area_id , date ) VALUES (1, 2, date() );
sqlite> select * from Calculations;
1|1|2|2015-06-24
2|1|2|2015-06-24
```

Comment: I was pulling it out of the database as an `int` instead of a `String`